# p-value adjustment for Local Moran's I statistic (LISA)

Tags: r, multiple-comparisons, bonferroni

I'm working with some exploratory spatial analysis in R using spdep package.

I came across an option to adjust *p*-values of local indicators of spatial association (LISA) calculated using [`localmoran`](http://rss.acs.unt.edu/Rdoc/library/spdep/html/localmoran.html) function. According to the docs it is aimed at:

> ... probability value adjustment for multiple tests.

Further in the docs of `p.adjustSP` I read that the options available are:

> The adjustment methods include the Bonferroni correction
>   ('"bonferroni"') in which the p-values are multiplied by the number of
>   comparisons. Four less conservative corrections are also included by
>   Holm (1979) ('"holm"'), Hochberg (1988) ('"hochberg"'), Hommel (1988)
>   ('"hommel"') and Benjamini & Hochberg (1995) ('"fdr"'), respectively.
>   A pass-through option ('"none"') is also included.
>
> The first four methods are designed to give strong control of the
>   family-wise error rate. There seems no reason to use the unmodified
>   Bonferroni correction because it is dominated by Holm's method, which
>   is also valid under arbitrary assumptions.
>
> Hochberg's and Hommel's methods are valid when the hypothesis tests
>   are independent or when they are non-negatively associated (Sarkar,
>   1998; Sarkar and Chang, 1997). Hommel's method is more powerful than
>   Hochberg's, but the difference is usually small and the Hochberg
>   p-values are faster to compute.
>
> The "BH" (aka "fdr") and "BY" method of Benjamini, Hochberg, and
>   Yekutieli control the false discovery rate, the expected proportion of
>   false discoveries amongst the rejected hypotheses. The false discovery
>   rate is a less stringent condition than the family-wise error rate, so
>   these methods are more powerful than the others.

Couple of questions that appeared:

1. In plain words - what is the purpose of this adjustment?
2. Is it necessary to use such corrections?
3. If yes - how to choose from
   available options?

Comment: I migrated this question because many very like it have been addressed here on CV.  See what you can learn from a [search](http://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=[multiple-comparisons]+benjamini), for instance.

Comment: @whuber Good idea. I didn't think about CV, but that indeed seems to be a better home for it. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

briefly, the problem that you are facing is called [multiple hypothesis testing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiple_comparisons_problem). It arises when you are testing, as the name indicates, many hypothesis at the same time.

Let's say that you have a given probability of incorrectly rejecting the null hypothesis (false positive) for a test, say 5%. As you increase the number of datasets that you are testing (in this case, each of the sets where you apply the local Moran statistic), the probability of observing in *any* dataset a false positive will increase, independently from the fact that probability of observing a false positive for a single dataset is the same.

There are many possible "corrections", which are the ones that you found, to correct this problem; if you really need a local statistic, you cannot dodge it. Otherwise, you can use the global statistic as a single hypothesis.